# How do I get connection pooling working on a PHP-CGI PDO iSeries Access UnixODBC Connection?

Tags: php, db2, odbc, connection-pooling, unixodbc

I am trying to get connection pooling working using PHP/PDO with a UnixODBC driver called iSeries Access for Linux.

I do not set the PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT in my PDO constructor as I want to use pooling and not persistence (I am in a PHP-CGI environment).

Using the "Connection Pooling" section of http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-linux_bestpract.html I have placed

```
Pooling = Yes
```

in my odbc.ini and

```
CPTimeout = 600
```

in my odbcinst.ini

**However, it seems that the ODBC driver is not connection pooling** because every page refresh generates the CPIAD09 related message of an incoming connection being made.

Here are my full ODBC configuration files:

```
==== odbc.ini ====
[AS400]
Description             = Production AS/400 Database
Driver                  = iSeries Access ODBC Driver
System                  = XXX.XXX.X.X
UserID                  = XXXXXXXX
Password                = XXXXXXXX
Naming                  = 0
DefaultLibraries        = USERLIB, BPCSF, ADV, WEB, RITAUSR
Database                =
ConnectionType          = 0
CommitMode              = 2
ExtendedDynamic         = 0
DefaultPkgLibrary       = QGPL
DefaultPackage          = A/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512
AllowDataCompression    = 1
LibraryView             = 0
AllowUnsupportedChar    = 0
ForceTranslation        = 0
Trace                   = 0
DSN                     = AS400
Pooling                 = Yes
```

and

```
==== odbcinst.ini ====
[iSeries Access ODBC Driver]
Description     = iSeries Access for Linux ODBC Driver
Driver          = /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib/libcwbodbc.so
Setup           = /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib/libcwbodbcs.so
NOTE1           = If using unixODBC 2.2.11 or later and you want the 32 and 64-bit ODBC drivers to share DSN's,
NOTE2           = the following Driver64/Setup64 keywords will provide that support.
Driver64        = /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
Setup64         = /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
Threading       = 2
DontDLClose     = 1
UsageCount      = 1
CPTimeout       = 600
```

Comment: Ok so as there is no question here and it looks like you know what you have to do, what do you need us for?

Comment: RiggsFolly, I have revised the question.

Comment: And I have revised my opinion of it also.

Comment: Even though I have updated by OBDC files as per spec, new page requests continue to create new connection messages on the DB2 as if the old connections are not reused or pooled.

In the documentation it suggests that the main reason to use pooling is to avoid this connection to the service (what the message is generated by), as this is the highest cost of performance.

Comment: I too am having a similar issue (no pooling) using unixODBC w/DB2 from Python (using pyodbc). I'm only having this issue with DB2; Starting to wonder if it's an issue with their driver(s).

Answer (score 0):

Increase the number of connection pool will always go on.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your response.  I have tried to set max pool size and min pool size.  Are you saying that I need to increase the connection pool size or are you saying that the messages will always go on?

Comment: What do you mean by this? Is there an answer somewhere in your words?

Answer (score 0):

```
Pooling         = Yes
```

This needs to go under [ODBC] in you odbcinst.ini and NOT your odbc.ini file

```
CPTimeout       = 600
```

Put this in your odbc.ini