# Connection pooling issues with unixODBC, IBM DB2, and pyodbc

Tags: db2, odbc, pyodbc, unixodbc, db2-400

**tldr;** Have a working setup of Python->DB2, using unixODBC, but connection pooling is not working.

I've tried using the driver directly:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=/opt/ibm/db2/lib/libdb2.so;Hostname=mydb2.domain.com;PORT=1234;DATABASE=database1;UID=user1;PWD=password1')
```

By driver name:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=DB2;Hostname=mydb2.domain.com;PORT=1234;DATABASE=database1;UID=user1;PWD=password1')
```

DSN:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=server1UID=user1;PWD=password1')
```

I've been using this Python script to test:

```
import sys
import timeit

#import pypyodbc as pyodbc
import pyodbc


#conn = pypyodbc.connect('DSN=server1;UID=user1;PWD=password1')
def query():
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=server1;UID=user1;PWD=password1')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("select current timestamp from sysibm.sysdummy1")
        row = cur.fetchone()
        print('.', end='', flush=True)
        conn.close()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex, end='', flush=True)

t = timeit.Timer(query)
count = 50
duration = t.timeit(count)
print("\n{count} @ {duration}/sec".format(count=count, duration=count/duration))
```

*(When logging is enabled, in `odbcinst.ini`, it shows a connection open/close for every query)*

In my dev environment the above gets around ~10 query/sec

If the connection is created outside of the loop, and cached, then ~120 query/sec

If I install the `ibm_db_dbi` and use `connect` the results are ~10 query/sec, and using `pconnect` ~60 query/sec.

I've also tried iODBC, but I can't get it to connect at all, and on Windows, using ODBC, connection pooling appears to be working as expected.

**Why unixODBC and not `ibm_db_dbi`?**

- `connect` doesn't pool
- `pconnect` fails catastrophically, and never recovers, after network interruptions. It's also half the speed of a cached connection.
- `pyodbc` seems better maintained than the IBM driver.

---

### Setup:

- Debian Jessie
- Docker 1.7 container
- IBM DB2 ODBC v10.5 library installed
- unixODBC 2.3.4
- Python 3.5
- pyodbc 3.0.10

---

### Configuration:

#### odbcinst.ini

```
[ODBC]
Pooling         = Yes
Trace           = No
TraceFile       = /var/log/odbc.log

[DB2]
Description     = IBM DB2 Adapter
Driver          = /opt/ibm/db2/lib/libdb2.so
Driver64        = /opt/ibm/db2/lib/libdb2o.so
FileUsage       = 1
DontDLClose     = 1
CPTimeout       = 1000
CPTimeToLive    = 100
Threading       = 2
Pooling         = Yes
```

#### odbc.ini

```
[server1]
Description    = Server 1
Driver         = DB2
```

#### db2cli.ini

```
[server1]
Database      = database1
Protocol      = TCPIP
Hostname      = mydb2.domain.com
ServiceName   = 1234
```

---

### References:

- [Using IBM DB2 with unixODBC (from unixodbc.org)](http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/db2.html)
- [Setting up unixODBC with a remote DB2](http://fractio.nl/2007/10/26/setting-up-unixodbc-with-a-remote-db2/)
- [Setting up the unixODBC driver manager (from IBM)](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/t0010406.html)
- [Similar question on SO that is stale, unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584050/how-do-i-get-connection-pooling-working-on-a-php-cgi-pdo-iseries-access-unixodbc)

Comment: According to [this](http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/conn_pool.html) you may need to set `CPTimeout` to a non-zero value in the datasource section of `odbcinst.ini`. Alternatively, you could use the DB2 driver connection pooling instead.

Comment: @mustaccio - I edited the question to add both `CPTimeout` and `CPTimeToLive`; I missed them when copying my snippet =S

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have `Pooling         = Yes` in the wrong place, it needs to be under the `[ODBC]` heading, not the driver heading

http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/conn_pool.html

Comment: I've actually got it in both places =S.  I originally had it under `[ODBC]`, but also added it under the driver _(was pressing buttons trying to get it working)_.  It doesn't work in either though =(